# How do I force a Blazor app to accept POST requests?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor

I need my app to allow POST requests from anywhere without throwing a 400 Bad Request error. I am using `<form action='/anotherurl' method='post'>` and need to be able use the parameters passed through POST on another page in my application. Note: I cannot use GET because I do not want the parameters visible in the URL.

I have tried adding @attribute [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken] to the page but that did not work. Is there a way to force Blazor to allow for the POST request to go through?

Edit: Here is the entire form

```html
<form action="/ClientReports" method="post" target="_blank">
    @foreach (var id in SelectedClientIds)
    {
        <input type="hidden" id="Params" name="Params" value="@id">
    }
    <input type="submit" value="Client Reports">
</form>
```

The parameters are added to hidden inputs and then submitted like a normal HTML form but when the navigation occurs the result is a 400 error. The same code with a GET request does work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you try `[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]` on the `OnPost` method?


`[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken] 
public void OnPost(string parameter1, string parameter2)
{
    // ...
}`

Comment: I am not currently using an OnPost method, is there a way to attach a method like this to the HTML form?

Comment: If you want to use form in blazor,you can try to use [EditForm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-and-input-components?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

Comment: You cannot use forms/POST in that way natively with Blazor - you need a new design or you need to add code to your server to accept a POST and transform the form data to supply as parameters to your Blazor app. Which are you using? Blazor Server or Blazor WebAssembly (Hosted or Standalone?)

Answer (score 0):

Adding `@attribute [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]` to the `_Host.cshtml` file will allow HTML forms to POST to a Blazor Server app.

Note: Since Blazor is a SPA this will turn off Anti-forgery globally, more code is required to turn it off for individual pages.